# Fedex API Python: Reference Tracking numbers do not exist

Tags: python, python-requests, fedex

The end goal is to use the Fedex API to read a spreadsheet of tracking numbers and then update their shipping status via the Fedex API

The first step was to attempt to  read the status of a tracking number via the API. To accomplish this is am following the [Track by Tracking Number](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-ca/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/Track%20by%20Tracking%20Number) documentation that Fedex has provided. It should be noted that there is a **Test Environemnt** and a **Production Environemnt** as I am still developing, my app is in the test environemnt.

Being in the Test environment limits you to use FedEx's predefined tracking numbers as described in the [Mock Tracking Numbers](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-ca/guides/api-reference.html#mocktrackingnumbersforfedexexpressandfedexground) list.

When executing the following script and inputting numbers form the predefined list we can categorize into 2 response types, an error or a success where an error indicates the tracking number does not exist and a success responds with the body as described in the fedex documentation

```
import json
import requests #used to make the HTTP request


SecretKey = "REDACTED"
PublicKey = "REDACTED"
 

#Make a call to the Authrization Endpoint
AuthURL = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token"
AuthHeader = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" #Content-Type tells what form the body takes
    }
AuthBody ={
    "client_id": PublicKey,
    "client_secret": SecretKey,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
AuthResponse = requests.request("POST",url=AuthURL,data=AuthBody,headers=AuthHeader)
AuthToken = json.loads(AuthResponse.text)["access_token"]

#Make a call to the Tracking Endpoint
TrackingNumber = input("What are you Tracking? ")
TrackURL = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers"
TrackHeader ={
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer "+AuthToken
}
TrackBody ={
    "includeDetailedScans": True,
    "trackingInfo": [
        {
        "trackingNumberInfo": {
            "trackingNumber": TrackingNumber
            }
        }
    ]
}
print("Requesting Data...")
RawTrackingResponse = requests.request("POST",url=TrackURL,data=json.dumps(TrackBody),headers=TrackHeader)
print(json.loads(RawTrackingResponse.text))
```

When using tracking number **797806677146** from the list we receive a success full response

When using tracking number **920241085725456** we get an error

Why do some of the reference codes work and others do not? is it an issue with the fedex api or my code?

Comment: "*we get an error*" isn't a particularly specific problem statement without additional clarifying information - can you provide a full stack trace of the actual error you're getting when invoking this code with that specific tracking number in accordance with our guidance on creating a [mre] as well as [ask]?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe FedEx is only using 12-digit tracking numbers these days. Your number that doesn't work is 15 digits. As I recall, FedEx used to have 15-digit tracking numbers so perhaps the documentation you read is old.

BTW, though your code uses the FedEx sandbox, it can work with real tracking numbers. I just tried it with a real (i.e. not sandbox) tracking number - no problems.